# How to install DevStack when there's a proxy with self-signed ssl certificate?

Tags: proxy, openstack

After setting `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` and `no_proxy` environment variables, the `stack.sh` run still fails perhaps because of the self-signed certificates.

1. how can I disable ssl so install can complete using non secure protocols?
2. how can I configure it so the install process will use my self-signed certificates?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/88105/erros-devstack-stableliberty-install-behind-proxy-self-signed-ssl-certificate/?answer=88293#post-id-88293

I've managed to get it working, but I also had to disable the tempest service (the testing integration tool)

basicly i added the `disable_service tempest` into the **local.conf** file.

Good luck :)

Comment: The ./stack.sh run still terminated with errors. I think additional configurations are needed but I don't know what they are.